# Lambda receives batch of messages but doesn't loop through them

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a NodeJS Lambda that is attached to SQS and receives a batch of 5 messages.

In my code, I use a `for await ()` loop to process each message. However, only one message is being processed.

Inside the `for await ()` loop, I delete the message from the queue, so it is not retried. Is that the correct approach?

And what should my Lambda code return exactly, as I cannot find any good, solid examples of a NodeJS SQS processor.

Comment: *"In my code, I use a for await () loop to process each message. However, only one message is being processed.*" - show the code instead of paraphrasing it. *"Inside the for await () loop, I delete the message from the queue, so it is not retried. Is that the correct approach?"* - no, it is not - the lambda services deletes the messages for you. And your code does not need to return anything.

Comment: Also: are you sure you actually got 5 messages? By default if you have e.g. <100 messages it is unlikely a lambda receives more than 1 message at a time.

Comment: @luk2302yea, I set the batch size to 5, and logged out `event.Records` which shows 5 messages, but then the log for the individual record, inside the for loop, only runs once

Comment: @luk2302 how are failed messages handled if i don't return anything or delete the messge myself? Surely SQS must be looking for some kind of specific return to know the message was processed OK, or is looking for any error exception to say it failed?

Comment: SQS does not care or know about your lambda. The lambda services gets the messages from the queue, invokes your lambda and deletes the messages if your lambda does not fail. If your lambda does fail it discards the messages, when the visibility timeout of the messages expire they become visible again and the lambda service will pick them up again.

Comment: @luk2302 if my lambda timeout is set to 30s (enough time to run and do its thing) what should my queue visibility window be set to?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html - at least 6 times the lambda duration. And apparently you are actually "allowed" to delete messages from the queue manually, I was not aware of that. And you are actually able to return partial failures if you want to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#services-sqs-batchfailurereporting . That means you have all sorts of options: manually delete the message, return a partial batch failure, retry the entire batch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254085/discussion-between-mr-pablo-and-luk2302).

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, it looks like the issue was due to calling a `return` statement inside a `for await ()` loop.

I removed these returns (they returned an awaited function that deleted the message from the queue) in favour of just continuing the loop. This meant removing all calls to the delete message function, and instead, let the SQS queue handle removing the messages itself, based on getting anything other than an error from the lambda.